# On proving that a random variable is a conditional expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

The definition of conditional expectation I am given and want to work with in the following proof is:

Let $X \in L(\Omega, P) $ on $(\Omega, F, P)$ and let $G \subset F $ be an other sigma algebra then there exists $Z \in L(\Omega, P)$ s.t.

1. $Z$ is $G$ measurable.
2. $E[Z 1_A]= E[X 1_A] \forall{A} \in G$

We call $Z$ the conditional expectation of $X$ given $G$.

Now I am trying to prove that if there is $Z = aX + b$ s.t. $E[Z] = E[Y] \iff a E[X] + b = E[Y]$ and such that $Cov[X, Y-Z] = 0$

then $Z = E[Y|X]$.

I think that If I show that $aE[X] + b = E[Y]$ thanks to the condition given from the covariance the proof should follow by definition. But when I calculate the covariance in terms of expected values there is a pesky $E[XY]$ that I don't know how to treat. How could this be done?

Is this true only for $X,Y$ jointly normally distributed?